# Parsing very large C# files (>50MB) with Roslyn produces CompilationUnit with 0 members

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to use Roslyn for modifying serializers code generated by svcutil.exe. basically, it contains several dozens medium classes, and two huge classes (reader and writer) that contains a function for every class in a very large schema, but nothing too crazy like very large strings or variable names.
It works great for medium files (7MB), but when trying to parse a very large source file (50MB, ~600K lines), I'm getting an empty 'Members' collection for the CompilationUnitRoot.
When turning on 'break on thrown exceptions' I see there's an InsufficientExecutionStackException thrown when loading the file.
Is there any way around this?

When I inspect the CompilationUnitRoot, I see that FullSpan property is correctly set, but the Members, Attributes, and Usings collections are empty.

Comment: why don't split the file into smaller files? I guess it's auto-generated? Then simply modify the generator to emit Reader and Writer into separate files

Comment: I discovered that this was caused by a monstrous (11K lines) if/else statement, so that wouldn't help.

Comment: it should help if you break the body of the blocks into functions: `if some_cond() return; else if (some_other_cond())...`

Comment: There are many possible solutions, the trouble is I can't use Roslyn to make the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this was caused by some monstrous (11K lines) if/else statement, which are parsed in a recursion.
Fortunately, these are all

```
if (...) return;
else if (...)
```

So I was able to pre-process the file and remove the 'else' keywords, breaking the recursion into to separate statements